# How to use session object after using sendRedirect method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a login page that uses a servlet name LoginServ. When user enter email and password, in the servlet varifivation is done. If the user logs in successfully, i set his email in session object like

```
session.setAttribute("email",email);
```

and after that i redirect user to home page using sendRedirect method like this

```
response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
```

now in the UserHome.jsp page i try to get session value by using getAttribute method, but i get null, that means session is not passed to userhome.jsp as i have user sendRedirect method. It must have created a new request and session methods, I guess. But what should i do to get the session value in userhome.jsp

Comment: Did you get your session by `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);`?

Comment: ...or worse : haven't you looked in the `request` object?

Comment: i did it by passing true as well, but issue remains same

Comment: @ParveenKumar :what you have done is correct. Please provide code from your servlet LoginServ. Maybe something in there is not correct